# When changing a VS project from using references to projects.config, how do I handle the references?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, github-projects

I am trying to migrate a .NET Framework 4.5.2 DLL, to a GitHub (GH) Package. The tutorial I came across ([Working with the NuGet Registry](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-nuget-registry)) was for the SDK style of project. Our .NET Framework 4.5.2 is older than the SDK style. I think it's called the "legacy" style of project file.

So, I've come across other references such as [Install NuGet Client Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools) and [Manage NuGet packages with the NuGet CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-nuget-cli). But these still leave out some details that I don't know how to address. For example, the Visual Studio project doesn't have a Packages folder. It also doesn't have a packages.config file. And it doesn't reference any NuGet packages. I believe I've got to create a packages.config file, then take the references from the .csproj file and copy those into a new packages.config file. After I copy the references out of the .csproj file into the packages.config file, do I delete those references from the .csproj file?

Another question I have concerns what goes into the packages.config file. According to this link [packages.config reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config), I must include the ID and version. I can just use the assembly's name for the ID, but I'm not certain about the version number. From within VS 2022, selecting each reference there's a "Version" attribute and a "Runtime Version" attribute. Which is the correct version I should use in the packages.config file?

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Quickstart: Create and publish a package using Visual Studio (.NET Framework, Windows)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio-net-framework)

Comment: Confusing question.  The first part suggest you want to *create* a Nuget package, but packages.config is only relevant to *using* a package.  Don't type it in, VS maintains it when you add packages to a project.

Comment: @HansPassant I may have misunderstood the instructions in the link I gave for Manage NuGet packages with the NuGet CLI. I took that to mean I needed to have a packages.config file, to publish a package to a GH Package. Is that wrong?